# Conditional expectations and probability

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation

[[image]]

I have solved the a and b part and one half of the c part.
I am getting $$P(X=x|Y=y) ~ Poisson(\lambda (1-p))$$
And when i try to get the expectation its not right .i get it as $$\lambda(1-p)$$ but the solution manual says its $$y+\lambda(1-p)$$..please someboday explain this concept..

Comment: $X-Y|Y\sim Poisson(\lambda(1-p))$. You omitted the shift by $y$.

Comment: Yes exactly this is the reason given in the manual..but i do understand this..can you tell my mistake

Comment: You have the term $(x-y)!$ in the denominator. It blows up for $x<y$. You can't obtain a Poisson w/o a shift at all.

Comment: But y is less than or equal yo x as given in the joint distribution so why will x be less than y..i am sorry if am annoying you..but really i dont understand the concept i guess

Comment: That's what I pointed out - that $y\le x$ (which wasn't explicitly mentioned)  - but that should hint that $X$ can't be Poisson and has to be $y+Poisson$.

Comment: Thnx but how does this strike to you, these things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36055/discussion-between-user312254-and-a-s).

Comment: @A.S. I think it is correct that $X\sim\operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666752/conditional-expectations-and-probability

Comment: @Math You are right - I got a little sloppy in my 3rd comment and used $X$ to refer to $X|Y$ (which is what the question was about).

Comment: No worries, I just spent a good hour doing the problem over and over trying to figure out what I missed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align}
p_{X,Y}(n,m) &= \frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda} p^m(1-p)^{n-m}}{m!(n-m)!}\\
&= \left(\frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda}}{n!}\right)\binom nm p^m(1-p)^{n-m},
\end{align}
so $Y\mid X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(X,p)$, that is, the conditional pmf of $Y$ given $X=n$ is
$$p_{Y\mid X=n}(m\mid n) = \binom nm p^m(1-p)^{n-m}.$$

To compute the marginal pmf of $Y$, we can sum the joint pmf over all values for $X$:

\begin{align}
p_Y(m)&=\mathbb P(Y=m)\\
 &= \sum_{n=m}^\infty \mathbb P(X=n,Y=m)\\
&= \sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda} p^m(1-p)^{n-m}}{m!(n-m)!}\\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}p^m}{m!}\sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n (1-p)^{n-m}}{(n-m)!}\\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda ^m p^m}{m!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n (1-p)^n}{n!}\\
&= \left(\frac{e^{-\lambda}(\lambda p)^m}{m!}\right)e^{\lambda(1-p)}\\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda p}(\lambda p)^m}{m!},
\end{align}
and so $Y\sim\operatorname{Pois}(\lambda p)$. The conditional pmf of $X$ given $Y$ is then
\begin{align}
p_{X\mid Y=m}(n\mid m) &= \frac{p_{X,Y}(n,m)}{p_Y(m)}\\
&= \left(\frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda} p^m(1-p)^{n-m}}{m!(n-m)!}\right)\left(\frac{m!}{e^{-\lambda p}(\lambda p)^m} \right)\\
&= \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^{n-m}e^{-\lambda(1-p)}}{(n-m)!}.
\end{align}

To compute the marginal pmf of $X$, we can sum the joint pmf over all values for $X$:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X=n) &= \sum_{m=0}^n \mathbb P(X=n\mid Y=m)\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^n \left(\frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda}}{n!}\right)\binom nm p^m(1-p)^{n-m}\\
&= \left(\frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda}}{n!}\right)\sum_{m=0}^n \binom nm p^m(1-p)^{n-m}\\
&= \frac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda}}{n!},
\end{align}
and so $X\sim\operatorname{Pois}(\lambda)$.

The conditional expectations can be computed directly from the conditional pmfs:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X\mid Y=m] &= \sum_{n=m}^\infty np_{X\mid Y=m}(n\mid m)\\
&= \sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{n(\lambda(1-p))^{n-m}e^{-\lambda(1-p)}}{(n-m)!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+m)e^{-\lambda(1-p)}(\lambda(1-p))^n}{n!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n\frac{e^{-\lambda(1-p)}(\lambda(1-p))^n}{n!} + m\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+m)e^{-\lambda(1-p)}(\lambda(1-p))^n}{n!}\\
&= \lambda + m,
\end{align}
and

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y\mid X=n] &= \sum_{m=0}^n m\binom nm p^m(1-p)^{n-m}\\
&= np.
\end{align}

Comment: Thnku Math1000..now i understand..and thnx to A.S also sorry for not understanding your comment

Comment: You could save some ink by noticing $p(x,y)=P(Pois(\lambda p)=y)P(Pois(\lambda(1-p))=x-y)$ which is to say $X=Y+(X-Y)$ sum of two independent Poissons which is a Poisson itself and $Y|X$, $X-Y|X$ are (dependent) binomials.

Comment: @A.S. I had that written in my answer before I read your comment that led me astray :)